# python package urllib2 working but cannot find it

Tags: python-2.7, package, urllib2, urllib3

I have a piece of code that is working:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://jr.jd.com")
print(html.read())
html.close()
```

My problem is I don't find "urllib2" package on my mac.

The python version is 2.7 (Apple built-in).

I tried `pip list` to list installed packages, but I found "urllib3" but not urllib2.
(I don't think the "urllib3" package includes "urllib2" by default - they works very differently. To use "urllib3", the first line of my code would have to change to `from urllib3.request import urlopen`.)

I tried `pip show urllib3`, and since I can find this package, the output is as expected:

```
Name: urllib3
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Then I tried `pip show urllib2`, and there is nothing at the output! - I think this means I don't have the package "urllib2" installed? (then why my code works?)

Could someone explain how my code works while I can't find the "urllib2" package? Many thanks!

Comment: `import urllib2; print(urllib2.__file__)`

Comment: @RedEyed Got it! Thanks!!!